# spring security every url is a blank page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Here's my security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("lt.nortal.lab.web.security")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Allow static resources to be served
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css**", "/js**", "/html**", "/bootstrap");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAuthority("admin") // allow public pages
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // other pages - authenticated only
                .and()
                .formLogin() // generate login form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll() // permit all to access login form (logical)
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll(); // Permit all to access logout url
                                                             // (logical)
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Here's my authetntication provider :

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String email = authentication.getName();
        String pass = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        User user = loginService.login(email);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid email.");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"));

        if (user.getRole() == Role.ADMIN) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"));
        }

        return new CustomAuthenticationToken(new AuthenticatedUser(user.getId(), user.getEmail()),
                authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
    }
}
```

login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginLogoutController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginLogoutController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    /**
     * Represents user login form.
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(final ModelMap model) {
        // add login form attribute
        model.put("loginForm", new LoginForm());
        return "login";
    }

    /**
     * Processes login form.
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLogin(
            final ModelMap model,
            final @Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm,
            final BindingResult bindingResult) {

        User user = null;
        // lets check for errors
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            // no errors, lets try to login user.
            user = loginService.login(loginForm.getEmail());
            if (user == null) {
                // something has failed, reject it with a global errror.
                bindingResult.reject("login-generic-fail");
            }
        }

        // at this point, we should have a user. If no user - return same login form.
        if (user == null) {
            return "login";
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

When I start the server and go to any page I get a blank page, empty html file. I cant seem to figure out whats wrong here. If you need anything else please let me know

Comment: Just want to check you actually have a request handler serving `/login`?

Comment: Yeah, if your login controller is like that then I cannot find anything wrong with it. Could you try debugging the `login` method and see if it is being hit? This will tell us whether the problem is in Spring or not.

Comment: @billc.cn no, login method is not being hit

Comment: can u paste the Spring' configuration XML file?

Comment: @Marijus no, the beans xml file...

Comment: I have the same issue @Marijus, Can you please explain how you resolved your issue.